# Traversing floating array for comparison in bash

Tags: bash, shell, linux-mint, awk

I am extracting float column from csv file and storing in `row_arr` array. Next am comparing a stored value in `sub_val` against the array elements. I want to store index of the matching element in a variable. I have the following code and errors.

```
declare -a fileList=(
"file-a"
"file-b"
"file-c"
)

loc='../myData/'

file_name="sample.csv"
png='.png'
sep=', '
txt='.txt'

fileList_size="$(echo ${#fileList[@]})"

row_no=1
counter=0
counter2=0

for j in "${fileList[@]}"
do
        echo "Sub Row No = "$row_no
        #Picking value from 2nd column for other sample file
        sub_val=($(awk -F, 'FNR = "'"$row_no"'" {print $2}' $file_name))

        #### Storing Time Sequence in Array from Other File
        while IFS=, read -a csv_line;
        do 
            row_arr[$rc]=${csv_line[0]};
            #echo "This is row array"
            echo ${row_arr[$rc]}
            ((rc++))
        done < $loc${j}$txt

        row_arr_size="$(echo ${#row_arr[@]})"

        for ((i = 0; i < ${#row_arr[@]}; ++i));
        do

            if [ $(echo "${row_arr[$i]} >= $sub_val" | bc -l) -eq 1 ]
            then
                    echo ${row_arr[$i]} ">=" $sub_val
                    p='p'
                    pos=$i
                    echo "Index is="$pos

                    got_row=$pos
                    got_value="$(echo `sed -n $pos$p $loc${j}$txt`)"

                    echo "File="$loc${j}
                    echo "Row No="$got_row
                    echo "Value="$got_value
                    echo "Counter="$counter2
                    echo "##################################################################"

                    break

            fi
        done

                counter2=$[$counter2+1]
                if [ $counter2 -eq $fileList_size ]
                then
                    echo $counter2
                    exit 1
                fi
        row_no=$[$row_no+1]
        counter=$[$counter+1]
done
```

and i get this error:

```
[: -eq: unary operator expected
```

if i replace `>=` with `-ge` then i get this error:

```
integer expression expected
```

Comment: That snippet alone suggests you will have a far easier time using a different language.

Comment: By the way -- in a well-formed question the above code would be a [mcve], providing everything needed for someone else to reproduce the bug (or test their proposed fix). The answer by Nahuel covers the most *likely* cause, but we can't tell that it's the *certain* cause because the code in the question doesn't run standalone (it isn't actually setting up the `row_arr` and `i` values you're using).

Answer (score 0):

Following command gives the same error

```
[  -eq 1 ]
```

it can occur if bc output is empty, which occurs in case of error

a simple workaround is to handle the empty output like

```
[[ $(bc -l <<<"${row_arr[$i]} >= $sub_val") != 1 ]]
```

- The double bracket is parsed differently if the first expansion is empty, first argument is empty string
- `!=` is a string comparison, handles the empty string whereas `-eq` requires an integer, because bc output can be `0` `1` or

Comment: Yes, you are right, `sub_val` was empty and i found that if you edit your csv file in which values are already separated by comma along with the space, and save, in LibreCal , then its going to overwrite previous settings and separate values by omitting the space. And that was the reason `sub_val=($(awk 'FNR == "'"$row_no"'" {print $2}' $file_name))` wasn't working and i could not get the value. Program is running but error is still there. I wonder if there's any syntax mistake.

Comment: This part was not in the first question but `sub_val=($(awk 'FNR == "'"$row_no"'" {print $2}' $file_name))` couldn't work because of parentheses which means sub_val is an array if output maybe you just need `sub_val=$(awk 'FNR == "'"$row_no"'" {print $2}' $file_name)`

Comment: if input is a csv the awk parameter -F must be set for example `awk -F"," ...`

Comment: Tried all different ways, doesn't work. 
`sub_val=$(awk -F 'FNR == "'"$row_no"'" {print $2}' $file_name)`
`sub_val=($(awk -F 'FNR == "'"$row_no"'" {print $2}' $file_name))`
Error still persists.

Comment: to specify field separator, `awk -F` must be followed by one char in case of many char is a regex separator so :  `ub_val=$(awk -F, 'FNR == '"$row_no"' {print $2}' "$file_name")` in case fields are delimited by a comma.